# A linearly independent set that spans a space

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, vector-spaces

So, in partial differential equations, we generate solutions for PDEs (kind of obviously). However, while the solutions we generate span the space of all solutions and are all linearly independent, the professor deliberately avoid use of the word "basis", citing some complication because the solution spaces are countably infinite dimensional (or even *uncountably* infinite dimensional), which apparently requires additional restriction before a linearly independent spanning set can be called a "basis." What is this additional restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be complete, in the metric generated by the inner product. This answer assumes your working in an infinite dimensional Inner product space.

The problem is that an infinite linear combination may no longer be in the space.

Comment: When you say "complete", is there a rigorous definition thereof?

Comment: Yes, inner product produces a metric. The inner product space is a metric space, a metric space is complete if every Cauchy sequence is convergent

Comment: How would a Cauchy sequence of a metric space not converge? And what does the inner product have to do with that?